# Xpath How to get one element using another element text value

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to create a xpath for my automated test. I have following code:

```
<span class="left-floated">
   <input class="PfcExecutiveBrief" type="checkbox" value="PfcExecutiveBrief" name="DocumentTypeResearch"/>
   <label for="PfcExecutiveBrief">Executive Brief</label>
  <br/>
   <input class="Memo" type="checkbox" value="PfcMemo" name="DocumentTypeResearch"/>
   <label for="PfcMemo">Memo</label>
  <br/>
   <input class="PfcOtherResearchForNaturalGasOrOil" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="PfcOtherResearchForNaturalGasOrOil" name="DocumentTypeResearch" disabled=""/>
   <label for="PfcOtherResearchForNaturalGasOrOil">Other Research</label>
  <br/>
   <input class="PfcProfile" type="checkbox" value="PfcProfile" name="DocumentTypeResearch"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="PfcOtherResearchForNaturalGasOrOil" name="DocumentTypeResearch"/>
   <label for="PfcProfile">Profile</label>
  <br/>
</span>
```

I want to create xpath which help me to check input element for selected label. So my question is, how can I get single input element for each label?

For example if:

```
label[text()='Memo']
```

how to get second input etc, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the `@for` attribute is misused here ([it should point to the `@id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140311/H44.html)), you can use it to resolve to the matching input that uses the same `@value` attribute.

```
//input[@value=../label[text()='Memo']/@for]
```

If the label might be everywhere in the document (instead of being a sibling like in your example), you can also search from the root again:

```
//input[@value=//label[text()='Memo']/@for]
```